# Python Machine Learning classifier for just one label

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm new to machine learning and looking to do run a training / testing dataset through a few classifiers, but the problem I'm having is that I only have one label for my data (Legitimate, currently set as an int so 1 for legit, 0 for not). Ideally I'm looking for a classifier that is going to run with just one label and either confirm or deny if something falls into that label, without the need to specify a second label or class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks.

Comment: Legit/not-legit is a binary classification. And you have two labels. Not quite sure sure I follow the question here..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
This is a binary classification problem, easy enough to research.

Comment: @Prune, thanks very much. I was simply unaware that this was a binary classification issue / problem (it being an area I hadn't yet even heard of). I'll have a look into that now. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lack of negative examples does not make this unary classification; there is no such modelling, as one-class has no discrimination, and therefore derives no new information from the data set.

As you've pointed out, there are two classes: Legitimate and not.  That's binary.  Use any binary classifier from your research that's capable of deriving boundaries from positive data only.  For instance, so-called "one-class" SVM is one such classifier.